# Display name Certificate OID - Windows

Tags: windows, certificate, oid, certutil

I installed a certificate in two windows machines (both windows 7 x86) and when I access the properties of this certificate by certmgr, the "Subject Alternative Name" section are different for both machines. The one that contains "2.16.76.1.3.3" is correct, is the oficial OID for "CNPJ". I tried to export the certificate of the "right" machine and doesn't work. I don't know if is there a way to map the OID to "common" names, but I need the original OID. The certificate installed in the two machines is from the same file (.pfx). Certificate details are below:

["wrong" properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SdTT.png)

["right" properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UU1Lw.png)

Answer (score 0):

If the certificate came from the same source (the same PFX) then the Subject Alternative Name entry is probably the same.  The difference is one of the two computers has had 2.16.76.1.3.3 registered with a name (CNPJ), and the other hasn't.

[CryptRegisterOIDInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptregisteroidinfo) can be used to register name/value (and other data) mappings for an OID; presumably the "right" machine had that called by some software at some point to register CNPJ.

This is just a UI display issue (Windows CertUI uses friendly names when it can, dotted-decimal OIDs otherwise).

Comment: Thank's for your comment. Yes, the pfx is the same. My issue is that I have a program that reads this entry (2.16.76.1.3.3), and how this computer has the entry "CNPJ" instead of the number, in this case my program is not working. I agree that in some point this computer is registering CNPJ as the OID, but i would like to know how it did this, I presume that it adds some entry on regedit.

Comment: @Lucas CryptRegisterOIDInfo is what adds the data (and persists it). Probably usually done during an installer, but you could do it at after querying and seeing the OID data is unmapped (CryptFindOIDInfo)